# Failed to Connect to MySQL using local socket/pipe MAMP

Tags: mysql-workbench, mamp

I am trying to connect Mysql Workbench with MAMP locally, but I am getting the error:

`Failed to Connect to MySQL using local socket/pipe at "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock" with user root`

[image]

Comment: Make sure the MySQL server is running, and is configured to communicate over the given socket (the configuration file should contain a line like `socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`).

Comment: Have you tried the Standard (TCP/IP) connection method?

Answer (score 1):

Сhange mysql port to 3306 in MAMP and leave "socket / pipe path" empty in MySQL Workbench. You can connect as root.

Answer (score 1):

In Mamp Pro, I've enabled Allow network access to MySQL / Only for this Mac.
My port is 3306. 
In MySQL Workbench, I've leaved Socket/Pipe Path empty.
I could now connect again.
Regards